# @Scope("session") and spring.session.store-type=jdbc, ERROR 30396

Tags: java, spring, session

I have been tried to use Spring session and Spring boot, but I could do it.

My objetive is save the currently session in a database with jdbc, and manager the scope of the bean with @scope("session") in a @RestController that calls to service.

When I write spring.session.store-type=hash-map in the application.properties file, the application work very well, however, when I interchange the property by:

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:as400://localhost/example
    spring.datasource.username=user
    spring.datasource.password=pass
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver

    spring.session.store-type=jdbc
    server.session.cookie.max-age=3600
    server.session.timeout=60
    spring.session.jdbc.initializer.enabled=true
    spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
```

The service starts normally, but when I try to consume it, 
I get the following error:

```
2017-05-24 16:27:44.329 ERROR 30396 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception



org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object] to type [byte[]] for value 'com.orm.control.UsuariosControlRest@27f9f7e6'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [com.orm.control.UsuariosControlRest]
```

I have the RestController class:

```
    @Scope("session")
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/UsuariosREST")
    public class UsuariosControlRest{
    @GetMapping("/readSession")
             public Usuarios getSessionUsuarios(){
                   return this.objSesionesService.getUsuarios();
             }
    }
```

The interface:

```
    public interface SesionesService {
        public Usuarios getUsuarios();
    }
```

The class SesionesServiceImpl

```
    @Scope("session")
    @Service("sesionesServiceImpl")
    public class SesionesServiceImpl implements SesionesService{

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("usuario")
        private Usuarios objUsuario;

           @Override
           public Usuarios getUsuarios() {
                  return this.objUsuario;
           }

     }
```

and finally one class named Usuarios

```
   @Scope("session")
   @Component("usuario")
   public class Usuarios{
        public String nombre;
        public int id;
        public String correo;

        public String getCorreo() {
           return correo;
        }
       public void setCorreo(String correo) {
           this.correo = correo;
       }

       public String getNombre() {
           return nombre;
       }
       public void setNombre(String strNombre) {
           this.nombre = strNombre;
       }
       public int getId() {
           return id;
       }
       public void setId(int id) {
           this.id = id;
       }
    }
```

I wrote in the three classes @Scope('session') because I found here

```
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session
```

that there are 3 ways for working with session in Spring. The first is with Session Scoped Beans (my way), follow by the inject the raw Session into a Controller and finally obtaining the raw session. I am using @Scope("session") in the related classes with the session, because the objects will be created for each user. If I only use @scope("session") in the first class, other classes will be "singleton" and when I modified some attribute in one session the other user will see it. Do you think that existe other way?.

Comment: I think you should make your service and controller classes really stateless. Then you can have them as singleton scope and don't need to serialize in the session (which i bad anyway, the session should not be that big). Otherwise you will run into serious performance problems, if your user base increases.

Comment: Also, the class `Usuarios` doesn't seem to be a service to me, it looks more like an entity.